# Required code to send notification through firebase

Tags: android, firebase

what i want is the sms should go automatically. The time, at which the message should go automatically, is stored in MySQL database.So i need the code that will keep on checking when that time comes and then send the message to that number automatically. Its a kind of reminder thing. The user will keep a reminder in application e.g.; i need to get a message after 1 hour. So after 1 hour the message should come. PLz help??

Comment: use cron job  it will run on particular time

Comment: what is corn job @iCoders

Comment: Cron is a time-based job scheduler.you can scheldule your php file to exicute on particular time